# unexpected changes after checkout

Tags: git

I have a remote GIT repository, which I clone locally.

After that I change the branch to another one, do nothing, then try to change to another branch, and GIT is saying there are uncommitted changes!?!

How in the world there are changes if I didn't do anything just changed branches.

See this action in the console.

[image]

I did set

`git config --system core.autocrlf false`

but it didn't help.

What's happening here, never saw such a behavior. The guy who committed to `perftech` branch works under Windows as me.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:
After long chat - we found the problem:
There are multiple contributors to this project and one of them has set a different CRLF value then the others which cause the problem.

**Solution:**
Make sure all the team is using the same CRLf configuration to avoid those problems.

---

#### How to see what has been changes?

First of all see what has changed and then try to understand out of it how come the files are modified.

```
git log HEAD^..HEAD

# to view the diff by words instead of lines:
git diff --color-words!
```

Once you see the changes try to figure out where did they came from.

Also verify that you don't track `filemode` in case the `chmod` was updated on those files

---

Git has something known as **3 states**

[image]

The 3 states are your

- Working directory
- Index/ stage area
- Repository

The important part of this structure (relevant to your question) is this:

**The working directory && staging area are shared not modified once you checkout branches**

Which means that if you switch branches they will remain in the previous state with all the changes you have made to them.

The only thing that is changes is your `HEAD`.
To understand what is HEAD read this out, it will explain in detaisl what is `HEAD` in git:

[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716)

Comment: There is no IDE running, or anything else that changed the files. I just changed the branch, the immediately tried to changed it back, and I've got that message about the changes.

Comment: What do you see in the diff?

Comment: try this:  `git diff --color-words`

Comment: Do you see any difference? i don't see any.

Comment: Same here, cannot see anything different.

Comment: If I run just `git diff`, then it shows like the entire file is changed, each line is prefixed by '-' then later with '+'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106831/discussion-between-codewizard-and-eugen).